# How to calculate the duration between 2 datetime in weeks and rounded up in Matlab

Tags: matlab, datetime

Given two `datetime`s `t1`, `t2`, I want to calculate the duration between the two in weeks, and rounded up.

The build-in `between` gives the number rounded down. For example,

```matlab
>> t1=datetime('20220817','InputFormat','yyyyMMdd');
>> t2=datetime('20220812','InputFormat','yyyyMMdd');
>> char(between(t2,t1,'weeks'))   % desire 1w
ans = 
  calendarDuration
   0d
>> t2=datetime('20220804','InputFormat','yyyyMMdd');
>> char(between(t2,t1,'weeks'))    % desire 2w
ans = 
  calendarDuration
   1w
```

Of coruse, `between` doesn't have to be used. `calendarDuration` is inconvenient for me actually, as I want the number of weeks -- not the calendar duration. But I don't want to deal with the true number of days between `t1` `t2` based on the exact dates.

How do I get the number of weeks rounded up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the number of days using the function [caldays](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/calendarduration.caldays.html), divide it by 7 and ceil the result:

```
t1=datetime('20220817','InputFormat','yyyyMMdd');
t2=datetime('20220812','InputFormat','yyyyMMdd');
ceil(caldays(between(t2,t1))/7)

ans =

     1

t2=datetime('20220804','InputFormat','yyyyMMdd');
ceil(caldays(between(t2,t1))/7)

ans =

     2
```